# Reverse translation dictionary Python

Tags: python, dictionary, translation

This is what I have ended up with after suggestions were made it appears as if the Eng dictionary is identical to the Tuc one. This program will translate English words to Tuccin but I can not for the life of me get it to translate Tuccin to English Pleae tell me how to achieve this. In the event a non stored word is input I have it set to just print the word itself. But i don't even manage to get the elif to trigger it goes straight to the else condition if it's not a stored English word.

```
Tuc={"i":["o"],"love":["wau"],"you":["uo"],"me":["ye"],"my":["yem"],"mine":["yeme"],"are":["sia"]}
Eng = {t: e for t, e in Tuc.items()}
print "ENG"
print Eng
print "TUC"
print Tuc
phrase=True
reverseLookup = False  

while phrase == True:
    translation = str(raw_input("Enter content for translation.\n").lower())
    input_list = translation.split()


    for word in input_list:

        #English to Tuccin
        if word in Tuc:
            print ("".join(Tuc[word]))+" *English>>Tuccin"

       #Tuccin to English
        elif word in Eng:
            print ("".join(Eng[word]))+" *Tuccin>>English"

        else:
            print word+" *Word Not Stored"
```

Comment: Typo: you did `t:e` rather than `e:t`, so you end up with a copy of that dictionary. Also, don't put the strings into lists - they only have one item, and it prevents you from reversing the dictionary.

Comment: And joining all the characters of a word back into the word is a redundant operation. Instead of e.g. `("".join(Tuc[word]))` you can use `Tuc[word]`. And, again, don't use lists when they're not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it currently set, `Eng` and `Tuc` are identical. It seems like what you want is

```
>>> Eng = {e[0]: [t] for t, e in Tuc.items()}
>>> Eng
{'yem': ['my'], 'ye': ['me'], 'uo': ['you'], 'o': ['i'], 'sia': 'are'], 'yeme': ['mine'], 'wau': ['love']}
```

As a side note, there's not really a need to make the values in the hash lists since they all contain a single string, but that's not a big deal.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo up there:

```
Eng = {e[0]: [t] for t, e in Tuc.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

You ought to do

```
eng = {v[0]: [k] for k, v in tuc.items()}
```

Or `iteritems()` with Python 2.

Note, instead of:

```
while phrase == True
```

You should write:

```
while phrase
```

Answer (score 0):

You can clean up your code quite a bit while fixing this error (you copied the dictionary instead of reversing it):

```
Tuc={"i":"o", "love":"wau", "you":"uo", "me":"ye", "my":"yem", "mine":"yeme", "are":"sia"}
Eng = {e:t for t, e in Tuc.items()}
print "ENG"
print Eng
print "TUC"
print Tuc
phrase=True

while phrase:
    translation = raw_input("Enter content for translation.\n").lower()
    phrase = translation.split() # empty input will break the loop

    for word in phrase:
        print Tuc.get(word, Eng.get(word, 'Word Not Stored'))
```

Answer (score 0):

This version assumes each word will have multiple translations (that's the reason you're using lists on each word):

```
from collections import defaultdict

tuc_dictionary = {
    "i": ["o"],
    "love": ["wau"],
    "you": ["uo"],
    "me": ["ye"],
    "my": ["yem"],
    "mine": ["yeme"],
    "are": ["sia"]
}
english_dictionary = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in tuc_dictionary.items():
    for word in v:
        english_dictionary[word].append(k)
english_dictionary = dict(english_dictionary)

print "ENG"
print english_dictionary
print "TUC"
print tuc_dictionary
phrase = True
reverseLookup = False

while phrase == True:
    translation = str(raw_input("Enter content for translation.\n").lower())
    input_list = translation.split()

    for word in input_list:

        # English to Tuccin
        if word in tuc_dictionary:
            print("".join(tuc_dictionary[word])) + " *English>>Tuccin"

        # Tuccin to English
        elif word in english_dictionary:
            print("".join(english_dictionary[word])) + " *Tuccin>>English"
        else:
            print word + " *Word Not Stored"
```